# Of all the electrical energy used in a home, is there any portion that won't eventually become thermal energy in the home?

Tags: energy, electricity, thermal-conductivity

Considering all of the appliances that the average home uses--microwaves, light bulbs, dishwashers, refrigerators--is it safe to say that all of the electrical energy in a home will be converted to thermal energy inside the home?

If you think about the resistance going through wires, that is converted to heat. The photons from the light will eventually be converted to heat. The refrigerator makes excess heat. Is there anything that doesn't end up as thermal energy?

Comment: Some of it will become heat outside the home - any light that escapes through the windows, or sound that's audible from outside, for example. Or any batteries that you charge up and then use outside (phone etc.). But I imagine the proportion that escapes will be small.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think about audible or battery use. This is more significant if one considers charging an electric car at home. But it is safe to say that everything else will eventually be converted to thermal energy correct?

Comment: Ah - of course the really significant one is air conditioning, which is specifically designed to cool the house and put heat outside. But I think if you're not using air conditioning, it's safe to say that the vast majority of power will become heat inside the home, at least for a time until it leaks out again.

Comment: @Klik: In the end, it will all become thermal energy. So the real question is just about the percentage _in the home_.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ways I can think of to export energy from a home that do not heat the interior:
Light through windows
Radio energy from transmitters (WiFi, cell phone, radio, power supply noise)
Sound from stereo/TV
Charge in batteries
Hot items carried out (coffee in travel mug)
Pressure in car/bike tires supplied from your pump
Vented hot air from dryer, shower, oven, furnace, water heater
Hair heated by a dryer and still warm when you go outside

Many ways, but a very small proportion of the electrical energy entering

Comment: And furthermore, all but the radio energy and perhaps some of the upward-directed light will still turn into local heat.

Comment: @rob:  depending on how local you mean and how fast you drive with your coffee cup

Comment: Also, electrically heated hot water that runs down the drain...

Comment: Air conditioning! I think that's the only one that's likely to be really significant.

Comment: @Nathaniel:  I'm embarrassed to miss that one, though I don't have AC.  Thanks

Comment: @Nathaniel that is a great point. I did not state it in the question, but I am looking for less obvious answers. My intention is actually to compare the energy flow from and to a house with regards to heating and cooling applications and how the use of specific environmentally (and economically) friendly solutions like deep lake water cooling or geothermal heating can affect it.

Comment: Sound doesn't turn its vibrational energy into heat at some point?

Comment: Mechanical energy rendered by dish washers, washing machines, food processors, blenders and any other appliance with a motor.

Comment: @Hoytman - that would also be converted to heat within the home.

Comment: @Nathaniel - I suspect hot water going down the drain (if heated electrically) would be significant.  In my house I think this is our biggest use of electricity in the summer.

Comment: A lot of the mechanical energy generated by the motors would be converted into heat, but a portion of it would be spent on the physical displacement of the object(s) that the motor was acting upon (as well as sound waves and EM waves, which were already mentioned.)

Comment: @Hoytman None of the appliances you mention displace anything permanently.

Comment: But the blended food doesn't then contain more energy.  When the moving parts come to rest, the kinetic energy will end up as heat.

Comment: How about water pumped up out of a well, and eventually released into the shallow septic leach field, or evaporated? You've increased the _potential energy_ of some water, but converting that to heat may be a very long and uncertain process.

Comment: Most of the energy of motion does may become heat, however not all of it.  In the blender example, some of the energy goes into breaking bonds between the atoms.

Comment: @Hoytman:  the motion of the blender heats the food (and the blender) slightly.  When you turn it off, all the energy shows up as heat.  Even physical displacement like a washing machine winds up as heat, in the clothes or in the machine.  If you spin up a gyroscope and take it outside you get the energy out, like the coffee and air pressure above.

Comment: Does that mean that all motion (as it slows due to friction) eventually becomes heat?

Comment: @Hoytman:  that is correct. Similarly if you run a fan, the blowing air will come to a halt.  The energy becomes heat.

Comment: Also don't forget *you* leaving the house with everything you've inhaled / ingested / absorbed, and you converting chemical energy to mechanical energy and such.

Answer (score 3):

My electric heat-pump removes more sensible heat from my house than it adds into it - and the electric bill comes to the house. So perhaps the answer should be no.

The point is the temperature of my house, may not be proportional to how much electricity we use that day.

Comment: "The point is the temperature of my house, may not be proportional to how much electricity we use that day." That's an excellent point. Can you elaborate on where the energy goes if it does not end up as thermal energy?

Comment: @Klik: It goes outside. Usually mostly into the air, although [some setups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geothermal_heat_pump) might also transfer heat into the ground.

Answer (score -2):

How about this also: you use electricity at home for heating, cooking etc to maintain the life of people and pets in the house. Then they go outside and perform mechanical work on something, e.g., at the gym.

For example, consider the reaction of ethanol burning (without worrying about details)

$C_2H_5OH + O_2 = CO_2 + H_2O$ + energy

Now imagine somebody cooking moonshine alcohol at home, combining [electrical] energy, water, and carbon dioxide. In principle this should be possible, the reaction is reversible. Next this individual consumes the product and goes outside to work out, or do some other great things involving some mechanical work. This would be the case of using electricity at home that does not end up as heat at home.

More seriously, we could consider other chemical reactions that can be carried out at home using electrical energy, that would produce some "fuel" for a human being (or his pet, his car, his toy helicopter etc) that would be able to use it for doing mechanical work outside of the house.

Comment: -1. The observations may be correct but this answer is about sociology, not physics.

Comment: Mechanical work done by humans or animals is fueled by the food energy they consume, not by electricity.  The energy used to heat food for cooking does not incorporate as food energy in the cooked food.

Comment: @J... - maybe not, but it heats up the body and causes the person to expend less calories keeping itself warm.

Comment: @MarkPattison Doesn't matter. The question is about electrical energy that does *not* end up as heat in the home, and you're talking about direct electrical-to-heat conversion in the home (ovens and heaters), so obviously it doesn't apply. The subsequent use of that heat to support *other* energy cycles (food / work) is irrelevant. The only way this applies to the question is in considering that some of the added heat stored at the person's body will not be in the home when the person leaves, but this has nothing to do with the work performed by the person.

Comment: @MarkPattison It does not.  Unless you keep your home dangerously warm inside, it is the human that is adding heat to the house and not the other way around.  The human is the hot object and the room is the cool object - heat flows from the human to the room.

Comment: But cooking certain foods increases the nutritional value. For example, humans cannot easily consume raw meat or potatoes but cooked meat and potatoes is ok. So electrical energy can be used to cause certain biochemical changes in food to make it convertible to chemical energy in the human body etc. Not to mention the possibility of producing synthetic food at home, or perhaps moonshine alcohol.

Comment: @J... Which part are you disagreeing with - "hot food heats up the body" or "this causes the person to expend less calories"?